# how to make columns appear one at a time

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a table consisting of four columns. I want first two columns to appear on the first slide while the third and fourth columns should be visible on the second slide. To some extent, I achieved this using the following code. However, my horizontal lines first disappear, and emerge again on the second slide. See images

[image]
[image]

Perhaps you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Results 1: Whole Sample}
\label{wholesign}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.94}{

\begin{tabular} {>{\onslide<1->}lc>{\onslide<2->}cc}

\hlineB{2}
& 3SLS & 3SLS & 3SLS \\ 
& ($t$)  & ($t-1$)  & ($t-2$) \\ [1ex]
\hline 
\alert {Outcome: entrepreneurship} & & & \\
Direct effect of FDI & \textbf{−} & \textbf{−} & \textbf{−} \\ 

Wages & \textbf{−} & \textbf{−} & \textbf{−} \\

Concentration ratio & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} \\
\hline 
& & & \\
\alert {Outcome: wages} & & & \\ 
FDI effect & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} \\
\hline 
& & & \\
\alert {Outcome: concentration ratio} \hspace*{0.7cm} & & & \\
FDI effect & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} \\
\hline 
& & & \\
%Total FDI effect & \textbf{−} & \textbf{−} & \textbf{−} \\
Observations & 3784 & 3782 & 3528 \\  
\hlineB{2}

\end{tabular}
    }   
\end{center}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Results 1: Whole Sample}
\label{wholesign}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.94}{

\begin{tabular}{lc>{\onslide<2->}cc<{\onslide<1->}}

\hlineB{2}
& 3SLS & 3SLS & 3SLS \\ 
& ($t$)  & ($t-1$)  & ($t-2$) \\ [1ex]
\hline 
\alert {Outcome: entrepreneurship} & & & \\
Direct effect of FDI & \textbf{AAA} & \textbf{AAA} & \textbf{AAA} \\ 

Wages & \textbf{AAA} & \textbf{AAA} & \textbf{AAA} \\

Concentration ratio & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} \\
\hline 
& & & \\
\alert {Outcome: wages} & & & \\ 
FDI effect & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} \\
\hline 
& & & \\
\alert {Outcome: concentration ratio} \hspace*{0.7cm} & & & \\
FDI effect & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} & \textbf{+} \\
\hline 
& & & \\
%Total FDI effect & \textbf{AAA} & \textbf{AAA} & \textbf{AAA} \\
Observations & 3784 & 3782 & 3528 \\  
\hlineB{2}

\end{tabular}
    }   
\end{center}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It neatly solves my problem.

Comment: could you explain this a little? Which of the packages you use is responsible for this? How can I read the code you put behind \begin{tabular}?

Comment: and is the scalebox important here?