# One-by-one column entry in beamer table with \onslide crushes

Tags: tables, beamer, columns, only

I would like to have each column of the attached table appear in a staggered fashion.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    

\begin{table}[ht]
    \center
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{r @{} l}}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{12}{c}{First Panel}       \\
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)} \\
            \cmidrule(r){2-7} \cmidrule(r){8-13} 
            \textit{VAR1} &        12&        &        44&        &      54&$^{*}$  &      34&        &     94&        &        0.1&$^{*}$  \\
            VAR2       &        0.034&        &        0.033&        &        0.062&        &        0.030&        &        0.040&        &        0.088&        \\
            \cmidrule(r){2-7} \cmidrule(r){8-13}
            \textit{VAR1}  & \multicolumn{6}{c}{XXX} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{XXX} \\
            \textit{VAR2}: &\multicolumn{2}{c}{YYY} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ZZZ} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBB}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{KKK} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MMM} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{YYYY}\\
            \midrule
            FE1 &  Y &        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        \\
            FE2 &  Y &        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        \\
            $N$             &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        \\
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{13}{l}{* -- $p < 0.1$; ** -- $p < 0.05$; *** -- $p < 0.01$.}\\
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I tried by using `{\begin{tabular}{l>{\onslide<2->}rl >{\onslide<3->}rl >{\onslide<4->}rl >{\onslide<5->}rl >{\onslide<6->}rl >{\onslide<7->}rl}` inside `tabular` option `{l*{6}{r @{} l}` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491317/how-to-make-columns-appear-one-at-a-time) but the outcome looks weird. Not all rows are rendered and I cannot see all the rules (`cmidrule`, `midrule`, and `bottomrule`).

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Your code does not compile

Comment: Sorry, I missed a `}` after the `{l*{6}{r @{} l}`. It compiles now

Comment: You can avoid all the trouble of placing the `*` in an extra column by using the siunitx package. Once you got rid of all the extra columns, I would suggest something like https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2000#a2242 to uncover the columns one by one.

Comment: Thank you. However, I got the extra columns from STATA and it'd be a huge work to change all the do files. Is there an easier latex based fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of uncovering the columns, you could play around with their colour. This way you won't influence the rules.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}<1-7>
\begin{table}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  >{\only<-1>{\color{bg}}}r@{}
  >{\only<-1>{\color{bg}}}l 
  >{\only<-2>{\color{bg}}}r@{}
  >{\only<-2>{\color{bg}}}l 
  >{\only<-3>{\color{bg}}}r@{}
  >{\only<-3>{\color{bg}}}l 
  >{\only<-4>{\color{bg}}}r@{}
  >{\only<-4>{\color{bg}}}l 
  >{\only<-5>{\color{bg}}}r@{}
  >{\only<-5>{\color{bg}}}l 
  >{\only<-6>{\color{bg}}}r@{}
  >{\only<-6>{\color{bg}}}l
}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{12}{c}{First Panel}       \\
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)} \\
            \cmidrule(r){2-7} \cmidrule(r){8-13} 
            \textit{VAR1} &        12&        &        44&        &      54&$^{*}$  &      34&        &     94&        &        0.1&$^{*}$  \\
            VAR2       &        0.034&        &        0.033&        &        0.062&        &        0.030&        &        0.040&        &        0.088&        \\
            \cmidrule(r){2-7} \cmidrule(r){8-13}
            \textit{VAR1}  & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textcolor<-2>{bg}{XXX}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textcolor<-5>{bg}{XXX}} \\
            \textit{VAR2}: &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor<-1>{bg}{YYY}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor<-2>{bg}{ZZZ}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor<-3>{bg}{BBB}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor<-4>{bg}{KKK}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor<-5>{bg}{MMM}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor<-6>{bg}{YYYY}}\\
            \midrule
            FE1 &  Y &        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        \\
            FE2 &  Y &        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        &           Y&        \\
            $N$             &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        &          8,340,000&        \\
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{13}{l}{* -- $p < 0.1$; ** -- $p < 0.05$; *** -- $p < 0.01$.}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Cool color trick, also for the fancy GIF animation :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks :)

Comment: amazing, thank you!

Comment: @Andrew You're welcome!